How to rotate input field of the pdf document with C#?
I have a pdf file with some text input fields.
I've installed the itext7 (8.0.4) nuget package for C# to work with pdf files and I need to fill in the text fields and then rotate them around 25 degrees.
I asked chatgpt for a solution, and it came up with this:
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("input.pdf"), new PdfWriter("output.pdf"));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

PdfFormField field = form.GetField("fieldName");
field.SetRotation(90); // Set rotation angle in degrees

pdfDoc.Close();

but there is no SetRotation method for PdfFormField. This is the main issue.
I am VERY new to C#, I mostly did Vue components with typescript so I can't properly navigate this issue.
On the offhand discussion - I am really close to just creating my own PDF library (probably shouldn't do that) - are there any good tutorials for creating pdf files from scratch? :)
Maybe I'm overthinking it too much. Maybe it would be easier to just convert the text field to plain text and rotate it instead? I don't need fields to stay as fields after I've filled them in.
SOLUTION (Based on mkl response):
var widget = field.GetWidgets()[0];
var chars = new PdfDictionary();
chars.Put(PdfName.R, new PdfNumber(degrees));
widget.SetAppearanceCharacteristics(chars); 


You can certainly rotate text, but I'm not convinced it is possible to rotate a form field in a PDF.

I see. Is it possible to convert field into plain text and rotate that instead? And if so does the angle HAVE to be 90 degree adjacent ?

Well, with iText you can read the text field contents and coordinates, remove that text field, and then draw that text at an angle of your choice at a position derived from those coordinates in the static page content.

You can set a rotation value for a field widget using the appearance characteristics dictionary of the widget:



Key
Type
Value




R
integer
(Optional) The number of degrees by which the widget annotation shall be rotated counterclockwise relative to the page. The  value shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.



(ISO 32000-2, Table 192 — Entries in an appearance characteristics dictionary)
The iText class PdfWidgetAnnotation has a setAppearanceCharacteristics method with which you can set a dictionary with an R value.
Concerning your request

I need to fill in the text fields and then rotate them around 25 degrees.

You can try to set the transformation matrices of the generated appearances to a rotation by that angle.
Unfortunately, though, this is not expected behavior by a PDF processor; in particular when filling text fields, a PDF processor is expected to set the appearance stream dictionary entries (except Resources and BBox) to their respective default value (see ISO 32000-2, section 12.7.4.3 Variable text). Consequentially, PDF viewers don't expect such special rotations in the Matrix entry and may ignore it.
In a quick test Chrome accepted the Matrix entry while Adobe Acrobat ignored it.

Anywhere I can read on code samples of said class or method? Also I just realised I don't need the text field to be a text field after I filled it in, so is it possible maybe to replace it IN-PLACE (same coordinates) this a plain text and rotate it on a free angle? (Not just 90 degrees)

You can add text to the static page content at arbitrary orientations.

Yes I've ended up using this solution and basically rewriting the entire code that was written using older version of itextsharp. It was quite a journey, so sample code would have been of use :) Anyways I've ended up with something like this: var widget = field.GetWidgets()[0]; var chars = new PdfDictionary(); chars.Put(PdfName.R, new PdfNumber(degrees)); widget.SetAppearanceCharacteristics(chars);
